# Flying Saucer/iText

Tags: itext, flying-saucer

I’m using Flying Saucer/iText to generate report. Now the report has a condition that if a specific condition takes place the report should move to next page of pdf and add the data on PDF and so on.
Regards
Pawan

Comment: the issue is the report I'm trying to generate is report of various reports. Now say if first report ends in between the page then the new report which is added should start from next page not in between. I'm not able to do so.  I'm using  ITextRenderer and passing html to it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to specify the page break in the HTML you pass to ITextRenderer by using the css property [page-break-before](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html#page-break-props).

For example:

```
<style type="text/css" >
    #page2{page-break-before:always}
</style>

<p id="page1">Content of first page </p>
<p id="page2">Content of second page </p>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly and added a page break exactly where I wanted.